# Preciso editar esse codigo javascript para gerar letras e numeros

Tags: php, javascript

O Codigo é esse abaixo eu preciso que nele gere letras e numeros em vez so de numeros como faço?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gerador de CPF e CNPJ V&aacute;lidos</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
&lt;<script language="JavaScript">

// ****************************************
// Script Gerador de CPF e CNPJ Válidos
// Autor: Marcos Guiga
// Site : Worldigital.co.cc
// Email: marcosguiga@hotmail.com
// Data:  19/12/2010
// ****************************************
// Função para gerar números randômicos
function gera_random(n)
{
    var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*n);
    return ranNum;
}

// Função para retornar o resto da divisao entre números (mod)
function mod(dividendo,divisor)
{
          return Math.round(dividendo - (Math.floor(dividendo/divisor)*divisor));
}

// Função que gera números de CPF válidos
function cpf()
{
           var n = 9;
           var n1 = gera_random(n);
           var n2 = gera_random(n);
           var n3 = gera_random(n);
           var n4 = gera_random(n);
           var n5 = gera_random(n);
           var n6 = gera_random(n);
           var n7 = gera_random(n);
           var n8 = gera_random(n);
           var n9 = gera_random(n);
           var n10 = gera_random(n);
           var n11 = gera_random(n);
           var n12 = gera_random(n);
           var d1 = n9*2+n8*3+n7*4+n6*5+n5*6+n4*7+n3*8+n2*9+n1*10;
           d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
           if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
           var d2 = d1*2+n9*3+n8*4+n7*5+n6*6+n5*7+n4*8+n3*9+n2*10+n1*11;
           d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
           if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;
           return ''+n1+n2+n3+n4+'-'+n5+n6+n7+n8+'-'+n9+n10+n11+n12+'-'+d1+d2+d1+d2;
}

// Função que gera números de CNPJ válidos
function cnpj()
{
          var n = 9;
          var n1  = gera_random(n);
           var n2  = gera_random(n);
           var n3  = gera_random(n);
           var n4  = gera_random(n);
           var n5  = gera_random(n);
           var n6  = gera_random(n);
           var n7  = gera_random(n);
           var n8  = gera_random(n);
           var n9  = 0;//gera_random(n);
           var n10 = 0;//gera_random(n);
           var n11 = 0;//gera_random(n);
           var n12 = 1;//gera_random(n);
          var d1 = n12*2+n11*3+n10*4+n9*5+n8*6+n7*7+n6*8+n5*9+n4*2+n3*3+n2*4+n1*5;
           d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
           if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
           var d2 = d1*2+n12*3+n11*4+n10*5+n9*6+n8*7+n7*8+n6*9+n5*2+n4*3+n3*4+n2*5+n1*6;
           d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
           if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;
           return ''+n1+n2+'.'+n3+n4+n5+'.'+n6+n7+n8+'/'+n9+n10+n11+n12+'-'+d1+d2;
}

// Função para escolher qual função chamar de acordo com a chamada
function faz()
{
          if (document.form1.tipo[0].checked)
                    document.form1.numero.value = cpf();
          else
                    document.form1.numero.value = cnpj();
}

// FIM
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="261" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#003399"><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Gerador
        de CPF e CNPJ Válidos</strong></font></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input name="numero" type="text" id="numero" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="168" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        <input name="tipo" type="radio" value="cpf" checked>
        CPF
        <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="cnpj">
        CNPJ</font></td>

      <td width="126" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="button" name="Button" value="Gerar" onClick="faz()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div align="center">
     <font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">© 2010 - 2011 por: Marcos Guiga
      <br> 
</font> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu criaria um array com todas as letras do alfabeto minúsculas e maiúsculas.

```
var alfabeto = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',...,'X','Y','Z'];
```

E seguiria utilizando seu código só que com os números correspondendo nesse vetor.
Por exemplo, seu código gerou os números 10,33,13,5.

Fazendo uma equivalência naquele vetor seriam jJme.

Por outro lado se o que deseja são os dois juntos, faria da mesma maneira, porém adicionando os números ao vetor também.

Assim:

```
var num_e_letra = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',...,'X','Y','Z']
```

Para isso o random é feito utilizando o length máximo do vetor.

**Edit**

Acabei de fazer o código abaixo, nele criei uma função que gera uma sequência de números e letras aleatórios, a outra gera uma letra aleatória.

random.html

```
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <p>KKK</p>
    <br>
    <button onclick="seqNumLetra()">Clique Aqui!</button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button onclick="seqLetra()">Clique Aqui Depois!</button>
    <p>Teste: </p> <p id="result">Resultado</p>
    <br>
    <p>Teste2: </p> <p id="result2">Resultado</p>
    <script>
            var letra_num = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
            var letra = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
            // minimo: 0
            // maximo: 33

            function genNumAndLetter(cont) {
                let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * cont);
                return randomNum
            }

            function seqNumLetra() {
                let a = letra_num[genNumAndLetter(letra_num.length)]; console.log("a: ",a);
                let b = letra_num[genNumAndLetter(letra_num.length)]; console.log("b: ",b);
                let c = letra_num[genNumAndLetter(letra_num.length)]; console.log("c: ",c);
                let d = letra_num[genNumAndLetter(letra_num.length)]; console.log("d: ",d);
                let e = letra_num[genNumAndLetter(letra_num.length)]; console.log("e: ",e);

                let seq = a.concat(b,c,d,e); console.log("seq: ", seq);

                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = seq;
            }

             function seqLetra() {
                let a = letra[genNumAndLetter(letra.length)];
                let b = letra[genNumAndLetter(letra.length)];
                let c = letra[genNumAndLetter(letra.length)];

                let seq = a.concat(b,c);

                document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = seq;
            }


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Voce poderia montar isso no codigo pra mim ? pois ele so gera numero, gostaria que gerasse letras e numeros maiúsculas, agradeço!

Comment: Mas você precisa de algo que seja totalmente aleatório? Parecido com algum hash, tipo a1H2jb3Y, ou algo mais específico, que você consiga decidir quando gerar números e letras, como uma função só para gerar letras.

Comment: Pronto fiz das duas maneiras, se tiver alguma dúvida só falar.